# List passed from View to Controller becomes null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been looking for a solution for this problem for a while and I have tried everything I found, but it is not working. I am trying to do an appraisal page in which multiple rows of a table in the database gets updated at once, so I have been trying to pass it through a list.

Here is the controller part:

```
     public ActionResult AppraisalPage(int id)
    {
        using (AppraisalsEntities db = new AppraisalsEntities())
        {
            var items = db.Sections.ToList();
            var criterias = db.Criteria.ToList();
            AppraisalCriteria myAppraisalCriteria = new AppraisalCriteria();

            //Add Variables to AppraisalCriteria table w/ 0 score
            for (int i = 0; i < db.Criteria.ToList().Count; i++)
            {   
                myAppraisalCriteria.AppraisalCriteriaID = myAppraisalCriteria.AppraisalCriteriaID;
                myAppraisalCriteria.CriteriaID = criterias[i].CriteriaID;
                myAppraisalCriteria.AppraisalID = id;
                myAppraisalCriteria.Score = 0;
                db.AppraisalCriterias.Add(myAppraisalCriteria);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            
            var myQuery = db.AppraisalCriterias.Where(x=>x.AppraisalID ==id).Select(s => s);
            var count = (db.AppraisalCriterias.ToList().Count - db.Criteria.ToList().Count);
            
            //ViewBags
            if (count != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.count = count;
            }
            if (items != null)
            {
                ViewBag.sections = items;
            }
            if (criterias != null)

            {
                ViewBag.criterias = criterias;
            }
            if (id != 0)
            {
                ViewBag.appraisal = id;
            }
            var ok = myQuery.ToList();
            ViewBag.ok = ok;
            List<int> scores = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5};
            ViewBag.scores = scores;


            List<AppraisalCriteria> AllAppraisalCriterias = new List<AppraisalCriteria>(db.AppraisalCriterias.Where(x => x.AppraisalCriteriaID > 0).Select(s => s).ToList());


            return View(AllAppraisalCriterias);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AppraisalPage(/*FormCollection>*/ List<AppraisalCriteria> AllAppraisalCriterias)
    {
        var criterias = db.Criteria.ToList();
      
        using (AppraisalsEntities db = new AppraisalsEntities()) { 
            foreach(AppraisalCriteria app in AllAppraisalCriterias)
            {
                AppraisalCriteria updatedApp = db.AppraisalCriterias.Find(app.AppraisalCriteriaID);
                updatedApp.Score = app.Score;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        var ids = db.Appraisals.Find(AllAppraisalCriterias[0]);
        return RedirectToAction("EmployeeList", new {id = ids.AppraisalBy});
    }
}
```

And Here is my View:

```
   @model List<Appraised4.Models.AppraisalCriteria>A
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "AppraisalPage";
    }
    <h2>AppraisalPage</h2>
    
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AppraisalPage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h1>Employee Appraisal Table</h1>
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    
                        @for (int 

i = 0; i < ViewBag.sections.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <tr><b>@ViewBag.sections[i].SectionName</b></tr>
                        <br>
                        for (int j = 0; j < ViewBag.ok.Count; j++)
                        {
                            for (int z = 0; z < ViewBag.criterias.Count; z++)
                            {
                                if (@ViewBag.sections[i].SectionID == ViewBag.criterias[z].SectionID)
                                {
                                    <tr class="control-label col-md-2"> @ViewBag.criterias[z].CriteriaName</tr>
                                    if (ViewBag.criterias[z].CriteriaID == ViewBag.ok[j].CriteriaID)
                                    {
                                        for (int x = 0; x < Model.Count; x++)
                                        {
                                            if (Model[x].AppraisalCriteriaID == ViewBag.ok[j].AppraisalCriteriaID)
                                            {
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(s => s[x].AppraisalCriteriaID)
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(s => s[x].AppraisalID)

                                                <tr>@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s[x].Score, new SelectList(ViewBag.scores, "", ""))</tr>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(s => s[x].Score, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(s => s[x].CriteriaID)
                                                <br>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Appraise" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

I have sent the ViewBags to show the Criteria and Section names from other tables. Also, to locate the column I am editing in the AprraisalCriteria table. Can someone help please?

Comment: This seems to be something you can easily debug. Place a breakpoint on the AppraisalPage action, set over and you'll be able to see where the list is getting lost or if it gets it at all

Comment: I did! And it seems like as I said the list is being lost when passed back to the controller. I am unable to know the reason and the solution tho!

Comment: I believe the issue you're having is with how MVC manages collections and maps them back to the model during post. You can verify this by looking at the HTML produced by your current code and looking at how your inputs are named.

See this blog post about editing collections: https://blog.learningtree.com/editing-collections-in-asp-net-mvc/

Also, as a side note. In my opinion, you should consider creating a better model for this view instead of using the ViewBag for your extra properties. Something like "AppraisalModel" which would have a collection of criteria as well as counts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with naming.

Your inner loop will create duplicate names because your loop starts with x = 0 every time you have a match. You also are creating editors in a broken sequence (not 1,2,3...) so even if you fix your loop you will have editors named 1,4,8,12, for example.

Editing collections in MVC can be tricky. See this post, specifically the section about "non-sequential indices", which I expect will help you reach the solution.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/